# Как отследить обращение к файлу?

Tags: linux, файлы, perl, файловая-система, взлом

Сижу на CentOS 7. Есть огромное приложение (биллинг). В основном, состоящий из perl-файлов. Внутри его структуры лежит файл "license.key", к которому идёт обращение из разных уголков программы. Я пробовал найти все упоминания ключа в приложении:

```
grep -r 'license.key' /usr
```

Но это не помогает найти то, что я ищу. Я предполагаю, что в каком-то файле этого приложения адрес ключа создаётся динамически, после чего идёт обращение по этому адресу, что и помогает обойти греп. Что-то типа:

```
my $url = "li" + "cens" + "e.ke" + "y";
```

Нужно получить имена всех файлов, которые обращаются к license.key. Подскажите в каком направлении двигаться.

Comment: Пользуйтесь отладчиком. Но так как это очень похоже на попытку взлома, то дальше оффтопик

Comment: да, у Вас скорее всего этот отладчик есть, но я не буду обсуждать тут взлом

Comment: Попробуйте отловить примерно так: $ echo '"li" + "cens" + "e.ke" + "y"' | grep 'l.*i.*c.*e.*n.*s.*e'
"

Answer (score 0):

Название файла не обязательно харкодить. Мало того, скорее всего, название указано в каком-то из файлов настроек или лежит где-то в базе.